# I cancel alarmManager but doesn't off ringtone

Tags: android

I am working with an alarm clock app. The app starts alarm but can't be off. The alarm on with system default alarm tone. But can't be off.Only when I forcely quit,The ring tone is getting off.I used toggle button here. I want to off alarm when toggle button is clicked after alarm on. The code I use is given below:

MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    alarmTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

}
public void OnToggleClicked(View view)
{
    long time;
    if (((ToggleButton) view).isChecked())
    {


        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ALARM ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentHour());
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentMinute());
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

        time=(calendar.getTimeInMillis()-(calendar.getTimeInMillis()%60000));
        if(System.currentTimeMillis()>time)
        {
            if (calendar.AM_PM == 0)
                time = time + (1000*60*60*12);
            else
                time = time + (1000*60*60*24);
        }
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, 10000, pendingIntent);
    }
    else
    {
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ALARM OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

AlarmReceiver.java

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm! Wake up! Wake up!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    if (alarmUri == null)
    {
        alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    }
    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
    ringtone.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Canceling the alarm won't stop the ringtone you are playing because those two things are unrelated. You start the ringtone from the receiver, but you have to stop the ringtone when you cancel the alarm or else the ringtone will keep playing.

```
{
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    // do something to stop the ringtone here
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ALARM OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: I also recommend using a foreground service to stop and start the ringtone instead of starting it from the alarm receiver because it makes it much easier to stop the same instance of Ringtone object that you called play() on